# Excel SpillParent and SpillingToRange Difficulty

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, spill-range

I'm trying to use `.SpillParent` and `.SpillingToRange` on Range objects in Excel in some UDF's and get unexpected behaviors when the range is not on the same worksheet that the UDF is called from.

(I know that I don't need a UDF like this if I use the "#" spill operator; I'm just using a very simple example to illustrate the problem).

```
    Function MyUDF(ByRef Target As Range) As Range
        Set MyUDF = Target.SpillParent
    End Function
```

If [Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10] is a range with spilling results from the formula in $C$2, and in [Sheet1!$A$1], I have "=MyUDF(Sheet2!C5)", I get the value returned from [Sheet1!$C$2], not [Sheet2!$C$2].

Example:

With [Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},

and [Sheet1!$C$2] = 57,

Having "=MyUDF(Sheet2!C5)" in any cell on Sheet1 returns "57", not "1"

My actual functions are more complex, but this simple example illustrates the anomaly. I can jump through some hoops using `.Address` and string manipulations, but seems to me I should get the actual first cell of the spilled range on Sheet2...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XU5H.png

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Asb8Fbj8gOc2g4NuDZ1ohh3A3w6xOA?e=Hh3Cpo

Here it is for me; it shows 57 vs 1.

Comment: Screenshot of results: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asb8Fbj8gOc2g4NwgYsff8OYjLH3jg?e=jYupV1

Comment: Perhaps a bug that's been fixed... refreshing that cell gives me the correct response of 1. Version 2108 (Build 14312.20008).

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14131.20326) 64-bit.
Still erroneous for me. (2106 build)

Comment: You could always try signing up for Office Insider to see if a later release fixes the issue.

Comment: Will need to check with IT dept before I try, but thanks much for taking the time to respond, regardless!!

Comment: Same error reported [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/spillingtorange-returning-incorrect-results-am-i/85dce3e6-33b5-4bd1-834b-82bfb6e49ad6).