# Return an array which spills if value is between

Tags: excel, vba, search, between

Is there any built in function to find any cells within a range which contain a value between a certain range? for instance using it on the below data and requesting values between 7 and 50 would produce the second column:

| column being searched | return values |
| --- | --- |
| 7.6 | 7.6 |
| 8.9 | 8.9 |
| 1.78 | 45.8 |
| 73.2 |  |
| 45.8 |  |

is there any built in functionality for this; or am I better off writing a for loop in VBA that loops through my whole data set? could I use the FIND and FILTER function in VBA to eliminate the VBA for loop?

Comment: Something like this would be VBA: `Range("a1").AutoFilter 1, ">7", xlAnd, "<50"`

Answer (score 3):

Yes FILTER:

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,(A2:A6>=7)*(A2:A6<=50))
```

[image]

FILTER is available with Excel 365 or Excel 2021

Comment: wow that was fast

Comment: How would I use this output as a variable in VBA? would it be an arraylist? or a range?

Comment: you can use Worksheet.Evaluate to return the values into an array.  But I am not a huge fan of using worksheet functions in vba.  If you want the array in vba to manipulate, then load the lookup into an array and loop that putting the output in another array.

Comment: You might be able to use `.SpillingToRange` as well, if you are trying to read the result of DA formula into an array.

Comment: @BigBen Sir, **WOW**, came to know for the first time `.SpillingToRange` is it the same thing like the `SPILL` in Excel Formulas

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - I'm not sure the docs have been updated yet. But yeah it's the range that formula spills to. Though apparently it [might be buggy](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/spillingtorange-returning-incorrect-results-am-i/85dce3e6-33b5-4bd1-834b-82bfb6e49ad6), untested. EDIT: oh yeah, [same bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68476260/excel-spillparent-and-spillingtorange-difficulty) reported on SO. Maybe it's been fixed.

Comment: @BigBen Sir, alright, it means a lot from your end, I am going through it. Thanks a bunch again to you & Scott Sir as well for making the community a wonderful place

Comment: thank you all! this has been very helpful :)

Comment: would i load the lookup into an array by doing 'someArrayList = worksheetfunction.FILTER(A2:A6,(A2:A6>=7)*(A2:A6<=50))'?

Comment: you need to `Worksheet.Range(...)` when refering to the ranges in vba.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple if condition:

```
=IF(A2<7,"Not in Range",IF(A2<50,A2,"Not in Range"))
```

Excel demo:

[image: Excel demo]

Comment: this isn't quite what I'm looking for as I want to avoid iterating through it.

Comment: please highligh on code block